# Guest Kali Linux GUI terminal window hangs in dual monitor layout in VMWare Workstation 17 Pro

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, terminal, vmware-workstation, lag

I wasn't having this issue a week ago. This has newly developed for me.

Here is the actual issue: When I run a command in the terminal while in dual monitor layout, the terminal window stops responding or responds erratically. If I switch back to single monitor mode, the issue completely goes away. Back to dual monitor mode, the issue returns. It doesn't seem like other items are effected. Web browser and general GUI usage work fine.

One thing to note is that the two monitors are running from 2 different GPUs. Again, this hasn't ever been a problem before. And yes, the GPU drivers are up to date. I updated them while trying to trouble shoot this issue.

Typing new commands, pressing up to cycle through command history, and any output from the terminal hangs. Sometimes, after a long delay (30-60 seconds) it may respond on it's own. Pressing enter doesn't always refresh the terminal.

I've used various hardware setup combinations with the VMs. 2, 4 and 8 cores with 2, 4 or 8 GB of RAM allotted with no change in terminal window response. So, I don't think it's a capacity issue.

The issue is persisting across 3 of my guest Kali VMs. One of which is a fresh install. At first I thought it was VMWare tools causing the issue, until I realized the issue wasn't happening while in single monitor layout with VMWare tools running.

I've tried not updating/upgrading in the fresh install, updating/upgrading a fresh install, updating/upgrading an established Kali VM. None of which had an effect.

I've mostly been using grep commands today for log analysis, but nothing taxing, and the logs are small (less than 20MB). The most taxing command I've been using is:

`cat Downloads/access.log | grep -E '[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}'`

Now, I haven't tried this in any of the other Linux distros terminal windows as of yet. However, I'm finding the issue very troublesome and I'm feeling rather confounded.

Thanks for taking the time to read and I look forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Kali (company) is updating the Kernel for various Video issues.

Make sure your Kali kernel is up to V6.

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade updates the kernel on my Kali systems

I am using a Kali VM on Workstation V17.

It may be necessary to follow up from time to time to get newer kernel upgrades and see if that helps resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, John. I didn't know about the dist-upgrade command and it will prove very helpful moving forward.. I did employ it, though sadly it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: You may need to try it from time to time to see if there are future kernel upgrades.